# Hibernate @Loader annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to use @Loader annotation in Hibernate. I wrote my own query in native SQL language to load my Entity the way I want (I want to cast one attribute).

The problem is that I've got this error when running the script :

```
Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: []
```

And I'm trying to load the Entity through JPA call (findById) or Hibernate load.

It looks like I didn't find the way to replace the question mark in my NamedNativeQuery, I thought Springdata would do it automatically.

Does somebody have heard about that ?

Thanks in advance,

LDF

Comment: Can you please eloborate? Questions seems to be a little  confusing. some code will help.